# How to calculate the length x when one side is not known in the cosine rule?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

the Question will become clear from this picture.

Here, the lengths of A and B are known and the angle a1 and the angle beta are also known. According to the cosine rule, ab is also known. But what is the formula for calculating the length cb when B is known and the angle beta is known?

OC is the line of construction so the length is also unknown.

Comment: What is CB? $\text{ }$

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti It is the length on the line ab when a construction line is drawn at an angle beta to the side B in the triangle.

Comment: Then it should be "cb"; you are denoting sides with capital letters and points with smaller ones ;)

Comment: after figuring out what ab is, use law of cosines to compute angle b, and then that will give you x.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I will correct it. Sorry.

Comment: After you find the length of ab (using the law of cosines), you can use the law of sines to compute the angle b.  Angle a can then be determined (a1 + b + a = 180).  Now, the difference between a1 and beta can be added to a to determine the angle ocb (the 3 angles still add to 180).  You now know all three angles of the triangle ocb and can use the law of sines to compute the lengths x and oc (since you know B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $A,B$, and $ab$. Use the sin law
$$
\frac{x}{\sin \beta}=\frac{B}{\sin \hat{Ocb}},
$$
where $\hat{Ocb}$ can be calculated again by the sin law:
$$
\left(\frac{A}{\sin (\hat{Ocb}-\beta)}=\right)\frac{A}{\sin(\pi- \hat{Ocb}-\beta)}=\frac{ab}{\sin a_1}.
$$

Therefore
\begin{align}
x=\frac{B}{\sin \hat{Ocb}}\sin \beta&=\frac{B \sin \beta}{\sin \left(\beta+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{A\sin a_1}{ab}\right)\right)}\\
&=\frac{B \sin \beta}{\sin \left(\beta+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{A\sin a_1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2-2AB\cos a_1}}\right)\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: this reduces the calculation. So, there is no need to calculate Angle Ocb. Great.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why $ \frac{A}{\sin(\pi- \hat{Ocb})}=\frac{ab}{\sin a_1}$?

Comment: But I think $\pi-\hat{Ocb}=\hat{b} + \beta$ instead.

Comment: @Mick Yes, I corrected it, thanks!

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Was the previous derivation wrong?

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime Yes I skipped an angle :D

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

sines rule:
$$
\frac{OB}{\sin(\angle OCB)}=\frac{x}{\beta}
$$

with $\angle OCB=180°-(\beta+\angle CBO)$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

\begin{align} 
2S_{\triangle AOB}&=
2S_{\triangle AOC}+2S_{\triangle COB}
,\\
a\,b\,\sin\alpha
&=
|OC|\,a\,\sin(\alpha-\beta)
+
|OC|\,b\,\sin\beta
,\\
|OC|&=
\frac{a\,b\,\sin\alpha}{a\,\sin(\alpha-\beta)+b\,\sin\beta}
,\\
x^2&=\dots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can write cosine rule for two different triangles $Ocb$ and $Oac$ with $Oc$ and $x$ unknown and solve them simultaneously.